# how to fix 'ENOENT: no such file or directory' error while using npm init?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a new project in node.js, I opened a new folder, opened it in cmd, tried to run `npm init` and when I finish to set up the project it gives me `no such file or directory` error

I tried to delete the node_modules folder, create an empty `package.json` file, and nothing works

that's the error:

```
    npm ERR!path C: \Users\ user\ Documents\ nodejs\ todo\ package.json
    npm ERR!code ENOENT
    npm ERR!errno - 4058
    npm ERR!syscall open
    npm ERR!enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Documents\nodejs\todo\package.json'
    npm ERR!enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR!enoent

    npm ERR!A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!C: \Users\ user\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm - cache\ _logs\ 2018 - 12 - 25 T08_30_30_726Z - debug.log
```

I expect to create a `package.json` file

Comment: is `npm` installed correctly on your system ? as `npm init` command itself creates a package.json file.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra yes, (I think at least)  when I do `npm -v`  it works (6.4.1) and I also tried to reinstall node.js. changed nothing

Comment: ok try to do `npm init` in a path where there are no relevant files installed ...i mean to say some different path..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to begin with nothing in folder?
When you enter

```
Npm init
```

It will auto create a package.json and you will enter your app info :D